# What is this old dual-disc metal object with a spindle? [more pictures added]

Tags: 20th-century, 19th-century, identification

[Updated: There are now pictures of both top and side views. Scroll to bottom of post to see the side views.]

While sorting through family artifacts, I found a black metal two-layer disc with a long spindle. One layer (marked "This Side Up") was about 5 1/2 inches in diameter; the other about 4 1/2".  The smaller disc had an inside ring with what appears to be lettering or symbols. See photos (four in all) for various views.

What is the object?

[image: mystery object dual discs and spindle]

[image]

Comment: Do any of the parts move or spin?

Comment: Dammit, I've seen one of these before...I assume that's just a random piece of cardboard,  and not the packaging the thing came in.

Comment: @Spencer Know how you feel, me too, just can't remember where / when. I'm wondering if this question might not do better on something like Engineering SE.

Comment: @Lars Or even https://mechanics.stackexchange.com

Comment: @Rjo please try to transcribe the "Letters or symbols", even if you have to draw them on paper and add another photo; on all of your photos they just look like random blobs of metal.

Comment: @Aaron Brick - The small disc and the spindle move. You can twist in either direction.

Comment: @Spencer - The object was between the cardboard. No idea if it was part of the original packaging or not. The letters/symbols do, indeed, look like blobs (the photo is fairly accurate). I'll see if I can improve my description by scrutinizing through a good magnifying glass (need to locate one; stand by for more info).

Comment: @Rjo Don't be disappointed if they turn out to be just random blobs of metal after all.

Comment: @Spencer - A few of the blobs look like numbers; possibly a few 6s r 9s. Or viewed another way, could be lowercase d's.

Comment: So, moderators -- what does one do in a case like this? Do I cross-post in Mechanics and/or Engineering with a pointer back to here? Ask for it to be migrated for me to one and, if needed, subsequently to the other?

Comment: I've asked the moderators for those two sites whether they think the question is a good fit.  Mechanics declined the migration and engineering did not answer two queries.  I don't think we can migrate.  (one of the mechanics mods is intrigued by the question, but can't answer it.)

Comment: Is there anyway to include a picture of a side-on view to show the edge straight on?

Comment: @Paulster - Added the side view to the original post.

Comment: Since we are doing practical archaeology here: It would be nice to have each view uploaded as one individual highres picture, "the find context" a bit elaborated (anything looking realted to that?) and *exact* measurements. The "letters or symbols" are either out of focus or not legible? Eaxct measurements for distance between discs?

Comment: It looks like part of a turntable: https://www.google.es/url?sa=i&source=imgres&cd=&cad=rja&uact=8&ved=2ahUKEwiDnq2ToPXeAhUPdcAKHfk0DpUQjRx6BAgBEAU&url=https%3A%2F%2Fwww.searspartsdirect.com%2Fmodel-number%2F14397921800%2F3028%2F0311600.html&psig=AOvVaw1XSERvMpLmCO-Wm5zFb9Kj&ust=1543431398366514

Comment: My association is that it could be a space part for a lawn mover. The "spindle" would do the cutting.